# a question about how to use 'the'

Tags: vocabulary

Which way is correct?

```
1. For the 5th,7th and 8th sets of parameters
2. For the 5th, the 7th and the 8th sets of parameters
```

Thanks!!

Comment: See [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is correct:

> For the 5th,7th and 8th sets of parameters

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you need to clearly state "the second way  (2) is correct" and then give reasons why along with some supporting evidence.